# How to remove the Google App Engine default header when fetching a URL?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-headers, craigslist

I'm trying to build a small app on GAE to help me manage the craigslist listing I'm interested in. I want to fetch some data from these listings from my app, but every time I do so I get a 404 from craigslist.

After some investigation it turns out my code is not the culprit: craigslist looks at the HTTP headers and systematically returns a 404 when it finds "AppEngine-Google" in the User-Agent header!

You can see that with curl:

```
curl http://sfbay.craigslist.org/
```

works (returns the page).

```
curl http://sfbay.craigslist.org/ --header "User-Agent: AppEngine-Google"
```

doesn't give anything.

Any idea how I could remove this header which is set by default by GAE? Or another idea to get around the issue?

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to prevent App Engine from identifying itself when making outgoing requests. This is to prevent abuse.

If Craigslist have chosen to blacklist App Engine, you need to talk to them about it, not attempt to evade it.